# simple problem on apache site gets downloaded

Tags: apache-http-server

I created a lamp (Linux Apache Mysql PHP) installation on a home computer.
I downloaded a package known as ilias and extracted it in document root as

```
/var/www/ilias
```

now when ever I try to install it as per instructions
http:///ilias/

I see the directory ilias getting downloaded as a bundle of zip files on my local machine.

How ever when I go the computer where it is actually installed and there I do 
http://localhost/ilias

then I can see the installation screen.

I am not able to understand why is this happening.
Following is my vhost configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all

        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
~
```

Here is apache log when I access the site on machine where it actually is 
as hxxp://localhost

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Feb/2011:22:18:29 +0530] "GET /ilias/templates/default/images/ButtonsBack.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://localhost/ilias/templates/default/delos.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.8) Gecko/2009033100 Ubuntu/9.04 (jaunty) Firefox/3.0.8"
```

but when I do http://192.168.43.129/ilias/

I do not see any entry in /var/log/apache2/access.log .
The most surprising part of this problem is I have installed Ubuntu in a Vmware running on a Laptop.
The IP of Guest Ubuntu is  192.168.43.129
and that of host Ubuntu is 192.168.1.3

Comment: Are you sure you should be typing hxxp? Shouldn't it be http?

Comment: Due to spam filter policy to put my post on this forum I can not give more than 2 urls when I put my question with http then the forum's spam filter do not allow me to post so I have to put hxxp instead of http.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got a solution to above problem

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www
#Remove the 4 lines below had created problem that site started getting downloaded
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>



        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

This configuration worked.